# When does a magical flame become nonmagical?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-types

Imagine Bob the wizard casts *Fire Bolt* on a barn full of hay. Mike, the bad guy with *Armor of Invulnerability*, is inside the barn. The *Fire Bolt* sets the hay ablaze, and Mike takes fire damage from it. **Is this fire damage magical? When does magical fire become nonmagical?**

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate because it has been asked before.